# How can I stop my relay chattering as the voltage falls?

Tags: capacitor, relay, 12v

I'm powering a relay from a 12v power source, however this source does not immediately turn off, rather falls gradually for a 'fade' rather than straight off.

Unfortunately this makes my relay chatter multiple times in rapid succession open/closed just before it opens for the last time until next power on, as the voltage is just fluctuating around the critical level.

How can I avoid this? I tried some capacitors and while it helped I still wound up with it chattering at the end (Although slightly less).

Comment: you need to use a control circuit to activate the relay

Comment: What is your 12V source? What is causing slow turnoff (capacitors?) Can you build a crowbar or discharge circuit to ensure a clean shutdown?

Comment: Do I understand you to say that when you turn off the 12 V power source, the relay chatters a bit as the power source gradually declines in voltage?

Comment: Any reason why there is no loading resistor in your circuit in parallel with the relay coil? I think the cheapest and easiest way to drop voltage quick is that. Uses power constantly and dissipates heat though.

Comment: Can you draw the schematics of what you are asking? It will really easy for others to understand the setup clearly

Comment: Normally relays have hysteresis. That is: the activate voltage and release voltage are far apart with release << activate. It should not chatter unless it switches off some equipment which then causes the operating voltage to rise again. I think we need a diagram of how it all is connected together.

Comment: Probably your drive circuit is at fault because relays alone don't do that, though their drop-out at low voltage may be a bit sickly and slow causing more contact wear. Maybe you need to implement UVLO (undervoltage lockout). Show us a schematic...

Answer (score 2):

You can use an op amp to operate the relay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLgx3C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When power is turned off, voltage starts to drop. once it reached 11 V, the op amp will deactivate the transistor base and turn off the relay.

Comment: For 12V coils you might want to pick a lower zener voltage though. 12V coils can typically operate reliably down to 9V or so.

Comment: Suggest changing your opamp for a comparator, which is designed for exactly this sort of purpose. If you only have an opamp you can do it, but it's not the optimal solution.

Comment: @ElectronSurf - "faster" is not the reason to choose a comparator for this (although for a simple application an opamp will work, especially if you have a spare one on board already). Opamps are not designed to run open loop and have large differential voltages on their inputs, for example. Additionally, I would suggest putting in some hysteresis.